# Is VLC in 18.04 repository insecure?

Tags: updates, security, vlc

VLC website offers v. 3.0.3 download to fix previous version 3.0.2 security problem. Will 18.04 repositories be updated soon?

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?): [Does Ubuntu generally post timely security updates?](/q/119274/175814) and [How can I tell if a CVE has been fixed in Ubuntu's repositories?](/q/563408/175814)

Answer (score 7):

After typing the general approach: all bugs for VLC are listed as "community maintained", and most are "orange" and "needs triage" so there is no fix (yet). Links in the rest of this answer will explain those.

## General approach for any question related to security issue.

Ubuntu uses a website to keep track of Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures (CVE) issues. For VLC you can find it [here](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/pkg/vlc.html). Current list (and do mind the "community supported" comment since Canonical does not maintain VLC).

- ALL issues for 18.04 are listed as "needs-triage".
- Color codes are explained [here](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/priority.html) (Most are "orange": Open vulnerability that is a real security problem, and is exploitable for many people. Includes network daemon denial of service attacks, cross-site scripting, and gaining user privileges. Updates should be made soon for this priority of issue.)

That is on our side of this.

You can look up more information on each CVE with [this site](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/year-2018/month-7/July.html). Search with the CVE number related to the issue you are concerned about. Then you can keep an eye on the progress of this issue.

Regarding VLC: the update will arrive in Ubuntu as soon as someone offers a fix and this fix is tried and tested sufficiently. They are all security related so will be added to Ubuntu as long as the version you use is supported.

Regarding VLC 3.0.3: for software like this you might consider installing the version from them and not from Ubuntu software center. That is one way to eliminate the time it takes to get updates to our systems. But that also means a little more risky approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think the key to understanding what is up here from a broader perspective is that the package [`vlc`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/vlc) is not in Ubuntu [`main`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories#Main) but Ubuntu [`universe`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories#Universe).

To quote their description of `universe` (emphasis added):

> The universe component is a snapshot of the free, open-source, and Linux world. It houses almost every piece of open-source software, all built from a range of public sources. **Canonical does not provide a guarantee of regular security updates for software in the universe component**, but will provide these where they are made available by the community. Users should understand the risk inherent in using these packages. Popular or well supported pieces of software will move from universe into main if they are backed by maintainers willing to meet the standards set by the Ubuntu team.

Basically, there may or may not be an update. As the above description indicates, `universe` is a snapshot (essentially a snapshot of Debian unstable around the time of the Ubuntu release), and is not really maintained the way one might otherwise expect.
Personally I would advise caution regarding enabling the `universe` repository as it may be hard to keep track what installed software is actually expected to get updates and what is not.